# Require.js for accessing functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am trying to embed a JS code in an HTML file. While this works perfectly on console, I am unable to get the desired output by calling this JS file via HTML.

Here is where I am facing the problem in main.js:

```
require(["request","cheerio"],function(request,cheerio){
var request = require(['request'],function(request){});

request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    $('h3').each(function() {
        alert("hello")

    });
});
}
```

I get the error that require is not being used correctly in the following line:

var request = require(['request'],function(request){});

How do I go about this?
Thanks

Comment: just delete `var request = require(['request'],function(request){});` you can use the request variable from the function argument

Comment: @oliv37: I tried that. I get this error in that case: Uncaught TypeError: request is not a function

Comment: what is `request` ? is it a vendor library ?

Comment: Not sure, I was pretty much following the tutorial: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-node-js-request-and-cheerio-to-set-up-simple-web-scraping)

Quoting the site:  Mikael Rogers' excellent request module as a simplified HTTP client

Comment: maybe you could try `console.log(request)` to have more information. maybe this variable is an object, maybe you could try `request.get(url, ...`

Comment: This is what I get: { [Function: request]
  get: [Function],
  head: [Function],
  post: [Function],......

Comment: so you need to call `request.get(url, function(err, resp, body) {...});`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need

```
var request = require(['request'],function(request){});
```

Code below is enough

```
require(["request","cheerio"],function(request,cheerio){


    request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
       if (err)
           throw err;
       $ = cheerio.load(body);
       $('h3').each(function() {
            alert("hello")

       });
    });
}
```

Comment: This gives me the following error:

    Uncaught TypeError: request is not a function